# Retrofit + Robospice native crash on Android 6 - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android, native, retrofit, okhttp, robospice

When executing this line:

```
Response response = getService().auth(new AuthEnvelope(email, password));
```

inside **Robospice RetrofitSpiceRequest** class in **loadDataFromNetwork()** method - app crashes (sometimes not, but method doesn't return) with this log:

```
    12-10 11:59:30.510 17118-20973/com.package.name A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x586ef16 in tid 20973 (Thread-1060)
    12-10 11:59:30.612 196-196/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    12-10 11:59:30.612 196-196/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0/MRA58N/2289998:user/release-keys'
    12-10 11:59:30.612 196-196/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
    12-10 11:59:30.612 196-196/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
    12-10 11:59:30.612 196-196/? A/DEBUG: pid: 17118, tid: 20973, name: Thread-1060  >>> com.setinbox.game <<<
    12-10 11:59:30.612 196-196/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x586ef16
    12-10 11:59:30.628 196-196/? A/DEBUG:     r0 fffff7b0  r1 32f7b260  r2 716a43c8  r3 9dca9b00
    12-10 11:59:30.629 196-196/? A/DEBUG:     r4 00066102  r5 32f7b260  r6 7127a670  r7 0586ef02
    12-10 11:59:30.629 196-196/? A/DEBUG:     r8 9dca9b00  r9 9dca9b00  sl 9992df50  fp 9992dec4
    12-10 11:59:30.629 196-196/? A/DEBUG:     ip 9992dde0  sp 9992ddac  lr b497d07d  pc b4c96814  cpsr 000e0030
    12-10 11:59:30.633 196-196/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    12-10 11:59:30.633 196-196/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 003ff814  /system/lib/libart.so (artInvokeInterfaceTrampoline+23)
    12-10 11:59:30.633 196-196/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0018c79c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space 1 (deleted)
```

Happens **ONLY** on **Android 6** physical devices and emulators. On other Android version it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a gradle plugin **2.0.0-beta2** bug.
Solved by rolling back to **1.5.0**.